# Fastest way to get data from REST API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, rest

Im newbie in Python, this is my first work with REST API in python. First let me explain what i wanted to do. I have a csv file which have name of a product and some other details, these are missing data after migration. So now my job is to check in the downstream application1 if they contain these product or it is missing there too. if it is missing there should dig up back and back.

So Now I have API of Application 1(this would give the productname and details if that exists) and have an API for OAuth 2. This will create me a token and im using that token to access API of Application 1(it would look like this https://Applciationname/rest/< productname >) i get this < productname > from a list which is retrieved from first column of csv file. Everthing is working fine but my list is having 3000 entries it is taking almost 2 hours for me to complete.

Is there any fastest way to check this, BTW im calling token API only once. This is how my code looks like

```
list=[]
reading csv and appedning to list #using with open and csv reader here
get_token=requests.get(tokenurl,OAuthdetails) #similar type of code
token_dict=json.loads(get_token.content.decode())
token=token_dict['access_token']
headers={
'Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+str(token)
}

url= https://Applciationname/rest/

for element in list:
    full_url=url+element
    api_response=requests.get(full_url,headers)
    recieved_data=json.loads(api_response.content.decode())
    if api_response.status_code=200 and len(recieved_data)!=0:
       writing the element value to text file "successcall" text file #using with open here
    else:
        writing the element value to text file "failurecall" text file #using with open here
```

Now could you please help me optimizing this, so that ill be finding the product names which are not in APP 1 faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for your for loop. Like so:

```py
import threading
lock = threading.RLock()
thread_list = []

def check_api(full_url):
    api_response=requests.get(full_url,headers)
    recieved_data=json.loads(api_response.content.decode())
    if api_response.status_code=200 and len(recieved_data)!=0:
       # dont forget to add a lock to writing to the file
       with lock:
            with open("successcall.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(recieved_data)
    else:
        # again, dont forget to add with lock like the one above
        # writing the element value to text file "failurecall" text file #using with open here     

for element in list:
    full_url = url+element
    t = threading.Thread(target=check_api, args=(full_url, ))
    thread_list.append(t)
# start all threads
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.start()
# wait for them all to finish
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.finish()
```

You should also not write to the same file while using Threads since it might cause some problems unless you use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock)

Comment: Thank you @sergenp..it worked, now im able to reduce the checking time to 11 mins with sleep time of 0.20 between the start of threads

Comment: I again tried by reducing my sleep time to 0.001 im able to load in 52 secs, and if i use 0 secs im getting Exception sometimes, what should i do now. is it good having some sleep time ?

Comment: You are probably having troubles with the lock, I suggest you dont write to a file in a thread, you just append the results to lists, then when all the threads are done, write the results in lists to files